# why isn't my app running on iPhoneX like it does on simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone-x

Having a problem running my app on my iPhone X 12.1.4 vs simulator.  I am using Xcode 10.1.  When I connect to my simulator everything works as it should but when I go to run it on my phone, I get an error on this line:

```
let request = RideRequest(snapshot: self.rideRequests[indexPath.row])
```

the error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'username' in call
```

Also when I click on a button when installed on my phone, the app crashes but when run on the simulator - no crash and it works as it should.

One other thing:

```
 When I run and install on simulator no errors appear on Xcode but when
 I run and install on my iPhoneX, the 'red' ! mark appears with the
 error in Buildtime as a Swift Compiler Error but it will still install
 and run on the iPhone but for some reason crashes when button is 
 pressed.
```

RideRequest:

```
public RideRequest(String userId, String username, String currentAddress, String destAddress, Double latitude, Double longitude, Double destLat, Double destLong, Double ridePrice)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The line you included does not seem to map to the error you are receiving.

Comment: What do you mean?  RideRequest does include a variable username but again, this error does not appear when installing on simulator just iPhone

Comment: What I mean is, there is no reference to username anywhere in the code you posted.  If you want help with debugging `RideRequest` then you should include its code in your question.  Where are you getting username from?  It's not in the constructor.  Likely wherever you're getting it from exists in the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: I added to my question the RideRequest() but again, I don't get this error on the simulator.  I am running the same application on both the simulator and the iPhone.